# apache2 adding named virtual host over existing mod

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, rewrite

I have a `dav_svn.conf` look like this.

```
# mod-available/dav_svn.conf
<Location /svn>

  DAV svn

  SVNParentPath /path/to/svn/parent

  ...

</Location>
```

With this configuration every request to

```
numeric.i.p.address/svn/<repo>
```

work for each repository and work well.

Now is there any nice method for

1. preserving above configuration (`numeric.i.p.address/svn/<repo>`)
2. new root url such as `svn.mydoma.in/<repo>` works like `numeric.i.p.address/svn/<repo>`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use name-based vhosts for p.2
2. In the above case request to N.N.N.N/URL will try to find virthost with name N.N.N.N

Both virthosts must have the same config (or better N.N.N.N host must be [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#serveralias)) for name-host

With `mod_vhost_alias` and

`VirtualDocumentRoot d:/Sites/%0/web`

settings I see in error-log

`File does not exist: D:/Sites/my.ip.addr.here`